# Retrieve a value that i not bind

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a form whre I add from controller the element:

```
oInput.setValue(oField.value);
oInput.attachValueHelpRequest(this.handleValueHelp).setShowValueHelp(true);
```

I have also `oField.lookupOfSpecificInput`, a string conains the function that I call on server; the lookup is different for each Input Field. The server  answer with a list of suggestions.

In the handle help function I have:

```
handleValueHelp : function (oController) {
    var lookupOfSpecificInput=???????????????????

if (! this._oDialog) {
    this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.ui.demo.poa.view.fragment.FrgLookup", this); 
    }
    this._oDialog.open();
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of lookup from the input for which I need a help?

Comment: I pass the lookup by: `oInput.setBindingContext(oField.lookupOfSpecificInput);` Tis is the right way??

Answer (score 0):

You could try to proxy the handler trhough jQuery and pass "this" into it. Then you could fetch the value from "this" inside your handler.

```
oInput.attachValueHelpRequest($.proxy( this.handleValueHelp, this )).setShowValueHelp(true);
```

Dont know if that works in this context...